# Open ssl unkown protocol

Tags: c, ssl, get, openssl, routines

I wrote a code that worked for me great, I don't remember modifying it..
I compiled it today and tried to run it, but I got this error:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

I also tried to connect to the host name with the openssl client, but I've got and error says: Linked closed ping timeout..

I also tried to Install openssl again, and even install an older version but it didn't work..

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried to connect to the host name with the openssl client, but I've got and error says: Linked closed..

It sounds like the remote host is not available.  If you can't connect to the remote host using command line tools, then there's nothing you can do with your code to make it work.  Verify that the remote host is responding correctly first.

Comment: The host is available, I tried different hosts but the openssl client still keeps getting a timeout after: Verify return code: 18...

Comment: How have you verified the host is available?  Your example above suggests very strongly that it is not responding correctly.  If you have data demonstrating otherwise, please add it to the question.